# Linux whole-line sort does not sort correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, posix

I want to whole-line sort a file with the linux command `sort`.

My file `cat hello`

```
#_
*
#1
```

When run with `sort hello`

```
#_
*
#1
```

Because `#` stands before `*` in asccii table, my expected result is

```
#_
#1
*
```

Is there anyone can explain me why? Thank you.

Comment: My output is `#1` then `*` then `#_`.

Comment: @stephanmg your system may have different localization settings from OP's.

Comment: @Kent: Yes, I tried to encourage the OP to think about how `sort` is working or study the manual/implementation.

Comment: @stephanmg  oh... I didn't see your intention, my bad, sorry.

Comment: Well @Kent, then this might not have been too obvious. I just thought this is an easily researchable question, since one only needs to use `man` as you too pointed out. (Which one should IMHO check first thoroughly always)

Comment: Not a programming question; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552117/linux-whole-line-sort-does-not-sort-correctly where it may be on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By default gnu sort** doesn't sort bytewise, that is, **won't follow the order in ascii table**. Check this example:

```
kent$  cat f1
a
b
c
A
B
C

kent$  sort f1          
a
A
b
B
c
C
```

If you want the sort to sort bytewise, you can set the `LC_ALL`:

```
kent$  LC_ALL=C    
kent$  sort f1
A
B
C
a
b
c
```

Thus, with `LC_ALL=C`, you get your expected output too.

```
kent$  cat f
#_
*
#1

kent$  sort f
#1
#_
*
```

#### update

I just checked the man page, it states this literally as well:

> *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses
>   native byte values.